# Null or "0" in text box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i'd like to hide item (panel) when textbox value is 0 or null.

```
        if (Wier_r1.Text == null | Wier_r1.Text=="0") panelR1.Visible = false;

        else panelR1.Visible = true;
```

Why it doesn't work when in texbox is nothing - null. With 0 is working.

Comment: Then it's not *null*. Try *""* instead, or better, check what value Wier_r1.Text has when empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because TextBox.Text is never null. Is an empty string.

Your test should be:

```
 if (Wier_r1.Text == string.Empty || Wier_r1.Text=="0") 
     panelR1.Visible = false; 
 else 
     panelR1.Visible = true;
```

and the correct OR opertator in this case is || not |.

Comment: They are both logical OR operators, the only difference is || is shortcircuiting, | is not.

Comment: Right, too fast, the || is called conditional OR and the second one is the logical one according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=VS.80).aspx)

Comment: The `|` operator is a bitwise operator and should be used for bitwise operations. Since `bool` values only store information in 1 bit, either operator will have the same affect on `bool` values. But I don't consider using a bitwise operator on Boolean value to be very good form. It will looking funky to seasoned devs. I think this code should use `||`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think a text box will ever return null for the Text value.  I believe it returns an empty string.

You'd want to do something like this I think:

```
if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wier_r1.Text) || Wier_r1.Text == "0"){
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: `.Text` is a `string`; it is never `== 0`

Comment: No need to use IsNullOrEmpty and how come you check a string against a number (0)?

Comment: @Marc - sorry, instead of copying and pasting (the smart guy way) I just typed everything out again, I forgot to include the quotes.  Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

`.Text` on a `TextBox` is not going to be `null`. If you mean *a blank string*, then test against `""`, or use:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wier_r1.Text) || Wier_r1.Text == "0") {...}
```

Note also the difference between `|` and `||` which changes it to a short-circuiting "or" (i.e. if the first is true it won't evaluate the second) - which is usually prefreable, but which shouldn't change the *logic* in this particular scenario,

Comment: A much more understandable explanation of || and | than I managed ;-)

Answer (score 4):

```
panelR1.Visible = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wier_r1.Text) && Wier_r1.Text != "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

try:You are missing to use or `||` properly.

```
if (Wier_r1.Text == null || Wier_r1.Text=="0") panelR1.Visible = false;
else panelR1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: Both operators do exist in C#. `|` is binary, whereas `||` is logical. The bare result would be equivalent in this case. Of course the logical or fits much better here, you are right.

Comment: `|` is a valid operator for OR (see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx). The difference between `|` and `||` is that `|` will return true ONLY if BOTH values evaluate to TRUE. `||` will only check the second expression if the first expression evaluates to true.

Comment: @Mudu and DilbertDave Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DilbertDave || will only check the second expresssion if the first expression evaluates to false ;)

Comment: @Shree: Easy to get caught out on and worth knowing the difference, `|` can be useful in certain scenarios.

Comment: @thmsn: You spotted my deliberate mistake then ;-p

Comment: @DilbertDave: You don't mean `AND`, do you ("only if both values evaluate to true")? `|` evaluates both expressions and performs a bitwise `OR`, whereas the logical operator behaves as you describe. One expression may evaluate to `false` ideed when you use `|`.

Comment: @Mudu: yes - I knew what I meant but having brain to keyboard issues today.

Answer (score 1):

Try (|| operator)

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wier_r1.Text) || Wier_r1.Text=="0")
```

Or short form:

```
panelR1.Visible = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wier_r1.Text)) && (Wier_r1.Text != "0");
```

Answer (score 1):

Textboxes dont have nulls stored in them; they are always a string so you need to check for "".

```
if (Wier_r1.Text == "" || Wier_r1.Text=="0") 
    panelR1.Visible = false;
else 
    panelR1.Visible = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

try `(Wier_r1.Text == null || Wier_r1.Text == "0")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the Text property of a textfield is ever null. In doubt, use this method:

```
if (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(Wier_r1.Text) || Wier_r1.Text=="0") panelR1.Visible = false;
```

I'm assuming you want to hide the panel when there is no text, right? That would be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this

```
panelR1.Visible = !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Wier_r1.Tex) || Wier_r1.Text=="0");
```

And as others have stated,  the logical or operator in C# is ||, a single | is a bitwise or.

Answer (score 0):

Treat as object and use .equal for it..

```
    if (Wier_r1.Text.equals("") || Wier_r1.equals(0)) 
    panelR1.Visible = false;
else 
    panelR1.Visible = true;
```